# Prevent throw a report phtml error. I need "try and catch" and still working

Tags: magento-1.9

I've created a module to connect with an external API to know the shipping price. It works fine and I show the prices in the product page view.

The problem is when the API connection fails magento is throwing a report 503 phtml. I need to capture this error, show the product and disable "add to cart" button.

I think I need something like:

```
try {
   Connect   ( Problem here, it's throwing 503 page.
   show shipping price

}
catch (Exception $e){
  create report file
  Disable button and show one message.
}
```

The Code:

If the connection to the API fails, I get redirected to " report.phtml " I do not want this to happen.

```
$url_soap = "http://xxxxxx.com.co:89/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx.asmx?WSDL";
$soap = new SoapClient($url_soap,
    array(
        "location" => "http://xxxxxx.com.co:89/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx.asmx",
    )
);

$parameters = array(
    'Client' => $customerId,
    'From' => '$from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Units' => $units,
    'Weight' => $weight_value,
    'Value' => $price,
    'Width' => $width_value,
    'Height' =>  $height_value,
    'Length' => $length_value
    );
```

If this fails redirect me to report.phtml ( I don't want this  I want still in product view. )

```
$cot = $soap->MakePrice($parameters);

$shipping_price = $cot->MakePriceResult->Price;
....
```

If the connection to the API fails, I get redirected to " report.phtml " I do not want this to happen. I want to continue and check thinks like this:

```
if(!$shipping_price){
    echo "This product is not available for you";
}else {
    echo Mage::helper('core')->formatPrice($shipping_price, true);
}
```

Comment: please show code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing code I will take a wild guess.

Your Connect method does not actually throw an error for catch to well.. catch.

You need to write some code that checks the result of the connect.

Then use throw to throw an exception for catch to catch

```
throw new Exception('Unable to connect to external API');
```

Comment: Fixed. Adding this -> throw new Exception('Unable to connect to external API'); Thanks a lot guys